# Android fragments alertDialog java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android

I am trying to create a alertDialog with listView but if i select the alertDialog for the second time the app crashes giving me this error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: wishautomatic.com.wishautomatic, PID: 5342
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent
>   first.
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3880)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3709)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:490)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
>                         at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:356)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
>                         at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
>                         at wishautomatic.com.wishautomatic.CreateWishFragment$GetWishMessages.onPostExecute(CreateWishFragment.java:559)
>                         at wishautomatic.com.wishautomatic.CreateWishFragment$GetWishMessages.onPostExecute(CreateWishFragment.java:461)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        msg=messagess.toArray(msg);
        dialog.dismiss();
           final  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setView(listView);
                /**@Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wish message selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    WishMessage.setText(msg[i]);
                }
            });**/
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ViewGroup vg =(ViewGroup)view;
                TextView txt=(TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.textViewWishMessage);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),txt.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                WishMessage.setText(txt.getText().toString());

            }
        });
            builder.setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Select a wish message");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I have changed the alertDialog creation code to OnCreate method like this,

```
       public class CreateWishFragment extends Fragment {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialog=builder.create();
            builder.setView(listView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Select a wish message");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
            if (savedInstanceState!=null){
                wishfor=savedInstanceState.getString("wishfor");
                WishFor.setText(wishfor);
            }

        }
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            msg=messagess.toArray(msg);
            dialog.dismiss();
            //builder.setView(listView);
            alertDialog.show();
                    /**@Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),msg[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wish message selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        WishMessage.setText(msg[i]);
                    }
                });**/
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    ViewGroup vg =(ViewGroup)view;
                    TextView txt=(TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.textViewWishMessage);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),txt.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    WishMessage.setText(txt.getText().toString());
                    if (alertDialog.isShowing()){
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
                builder.setNegativeButton("BACK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });


        }
```

But the output is shown like this, nothing in the alert dialog box 
It shows only the title and no the list[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBZef.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is because you are recreating the same dialog again (I believe `onPostExecute` is called several times).

Build it once in your `onCreate`, then just `show` it on occasion.

This is also a better way since you'll build it once and not each time you show it.

If you wish to keep things this way, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655633/dismiss-alertdialog-android-removeview-on-the-childs-parent-first?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that might help you!

Comment: The app is not crashing, thanks.But the information in alert dialog does not display.